# Criptografar link javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá! Estou precisando criptografar um script, porém quando eu faço isso a url que estou usando como API para o ajax, não funciona.E o mais importante seria ocultar criptografar ela.

Comment: Acho que a sua pergunta ficaria melhor com um exemplo, sem a URL que vc quer esconder, claro. Um exemplo genérico.

Answer (score 1):

Esse texto não foi feito por mim, mas achei útil compartilhar com o pessoal.

Praticamente todo desenvolvedor web já passou por este problema. O javascript é hoje, uma das principais linguagens de programação da internet, e muitas vezes, nós desenvolvedores precisamos criar aplicações mais complexas usando a linguagem. E após horas de estudo e dedicação, surge aquela necessidade do PHP…esconder o nosso código para que ninguém possa copiá-lo, já que o javascript permite ser copiado direto pelo navegador. Veja aqui uma solução simples para ofuscar totalmente o seu código, tornando o praticamente impossível de ser decifrado.

Bem que o Javascript poderia ser como o PHP….eu já pensei, e provavelmente você programador web já pensou também. Só de saber que todo o nosso trabalho em javascript ficará visível para qualquer um, paramos e pensamos duas vezes antes de usar uma linguagem client-side. Recentemente,  tive problemas com uma aplicação javascript que desenvolvi…plágio. Então comecei a pesquisar sobre o assunto e cheguei a um veredito..

**Não é possível esconder 100% o javascript, pois o mesmo é processado diretamente no navegador…**
Entretanto, é possível **ofuscá-lo**. Assim o seu código fica praticamente impossível de ser entendido.

**Etapa 1: Comprimir o seu javascript**

Acesse o site http://javascriptcompressor.com/, insira o seu código-fonte e clique em compress. Isso ajudará o seu código a ficar com um tamanho reduzido, pois esta ferramenta irá retirar espaços em brancos, tabulações e comentários. Recomendo que mantenha uma versão salva do código original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Etapa 2: Ofucamento de código**

Aqui está a solução para este problema. O site http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/, faz algo que muitas ferramentas online não faz. Ele ofusca o seu código javascript com a função eval, e deixa-o totalmente imcompreensível para humanos. Até existem outras ferramentas ofuscadoras, mas esta que encontrei é a melhor de todas, pois a mesma não permite a descriptografia…

Para utilizá-la, cole o seu código no campo **Input**, desmarque a opção **“Move Strings”** e clique em **“Obfuscate“**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, o seu código criptografado será gerado no campo **“Obfuscated“**.

**Etapa 3: Usando uma 2ª criptografia**

Para dificultar ainda mais a visualização do seu código javascript, podemos usar uma segunda ferramenta online para criptografar / ofuscar o nosso código javascript. Basta acessar o site http://www.phpblog.com.br/exemplos/encodejavascript/, colar o seu código anteriormente criptografado, escolher a forma de criptografia e clicar em **“codificar“**. Eu recomendo escolher a codificação “High ASCII”, deixar marcado a opção **“decodificação rápida”** e desmarcar a opção **“caracteres especiais”**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Enfim…**
Recomendo manter sempre uma cópia se segurança (backup) do código JS original, senão você mesmo não poderá entender mais o seu código, no caso de alterar alguma coisa dele. Apesar do ofuscamento de código dificultar muito a vida de algum espertinho que quer copiar o seu código, ainda é possível decodificar. Entretanto, a pessoa tem que ter muita paciência, horas e horas disponíveis e o fundamental, tem que ser muito, mais muuuuiiito bom em programação e engenharia reversa. Ou seja, 99.9% dos usuários e programadores desistirão ao ver o código criptografado.

Font: [Blog Lucas Peperaio](http://lucaspeperaio.com/como-ocultar-o-meu-codigo-javascript)

Comment: Vou dar +1 pelo esforço. Mas o recomendado não é postar artigos que acha na íntegra na internet, e sim você fazer uma resposta com o que vc entendeu com seu próprio texto e citar a fonte. ;)